# Fail to insert data into SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have insert a correct query and tested it at SQlite browser but the data doesnot inserted into table through hard code in Java. This is my query for insertion: Cursor c= db1.rawQuery("insert into PackingList ('ItemType')values('"+getName+"')" ,null);

```
public class PackingChecklist extends Activity {

ArrayList<category> products = new ArrayList<category>();
categoryadapter boxAdapter;
Button btn;
 private String getName;
 String DB_PATH;

    final Context context=this;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    private static String DB_NAME ="test.db";
    SQLiteDatabase db1;

    private String selected;





  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category);


    boxAdapter = new categoryadapter(this, products);

    /*ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);*/
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    final Context context = this;





    DBMain db;

    db = new DBMain(this);



    try {



         db.createDB();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {



        throw new Error("Database not created....");

    }



    try { 

        db.openDB();



    }catch(SQLException sqle){



        throw sqle;

    }





    db1=openOrCreateDatabase("test",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);

    Cursor c= db1.rawQuery("select * from PackingList",null);



    c.moveToFirst();



    String temp="";


    while(! c.isAfterLast())

    {


        String s3=c.getString(1);




        temp="\n ItemName:"+s3;



        c.moveToNext();
        products.add(new category(temp));
    }


    boxAdapter = new categoryadapter(this, products);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);










    //click to add function
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //get the dialog view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.insert);


            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text
                                     getName=userInput.getText().toString();



                                     products.add(new category(getName));
                                     boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                     Cursor c= db1.rawQuery("insert into PackingList ('ItemType')values('"+getName+"')" ,null);
                                     // db1.execSQL("insert into PackingList (ItemType)values('"+getName+"')" );
                                      /*String d="insert into PackingList (ItemType)values('"+getName+"')";

                                        db1.execSQL(d);*/
                                     /*ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                        cv.put("ItemType", getName);
                                        db1.insert("PackingList", null, cv); */


                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }

    });


    //delete function
    lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

              selected = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();

             AlertDialog.Builder ad  = new AlertDialog.Builder(PackingChecklist.this);
             ad.setTitle("Delete?");
             ad.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + selected+"?");
             final int positionToRemove = arg2;
             ad.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
             ad.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
             {
                            products.remove(positionToRemove);
                            boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            String d="DELETE FROM PackingList WHERE ItemType='"+selected+"'";

                            db1.execSQL(d);

                    }
             });
             ad.show();
            return false;
        }

    });
    //click item
    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {


            Intent i = new Intent(PackingChecklist.this, PackingContent.class);
            startActivity(i);



        }






    });


  }






}
```

This is my DB helper class 
    public class DBMain extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static String DB_PATH= "data/data/com.example.trippreparationmanager/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "test";

private SQLiteDatabase dbObj;

private final Context context;



public DBMain(Context context) {

    super(context,  DB_NAME , null, 3);

    this. context  = context;

}



public void createDB() throws IOException {



        this.getReadableDatabase();

        Log.i("Readable ends....................","end");



        try {

            copyDB();

            Log.i("copy db ends....................","end");



        } catch (IOException e) {



            throw new Error("Error copying database");

    }

}



private boolean checkDB(){



    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;



    try{

        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        Log.i("myPath ......",path);

        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);



        Log.i("myPath ......",path);

        if (checkDB!=null)

        {

            Cursor c= checkDB.rawQuery("select * from PackingList", null);

            Log.i("Cursor.......",c.getString(0));

            c.moveToFirst();

            String contents[]=new String[80];

            int flag=0;



            while(! c.isAfterLast())

            {

                String temp="";

                String s2=c.getString(0);

                String s3=c.getString(1);



                temp=temp+"\n ListId:"+s2+"\tItemType:"+s3;

                contents[flag]=temp;

                flag=flag+1;



                Log.i("DB values.........",temp);

                c.moveToNext();



            }

        }

           else

        {

            return false;

        }



    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    if(checkDB != null){



        checkDB.close();



    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;

}



public void copyDB() throws IOException{

    try {

        Log.i("inside copyDB....................","start");



        InputStream ip =  context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME+".db");

        Log.i("Input Stream....",ip+"");

        String op=  DB_PATH  +  DB_NAME ;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( op);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;

        while ((length = ip.read(buffer))>0){

            output.write(buffer, 0, length);

            Log.i("Content.... ",length+"");

        }

        output.flush();

        output.close();

        ip.close();

    }

    catch (IOException e) {

        Log.v("error", e.toString());

    }

}



public void openDB() throws SQLException {



    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    dbObj = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    Log.i("open DB......",dbObj.toString());

}



@Override

public synchronized void close() {



    if(dbObj != null)

        dbObj.close();



    super.close();

}



@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {



}



@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {



}

}
```

Comment: I already did the thing as you mentioned, but the result is still the same.

Comment: I'd posted my DB helper.

Answer (score 2):

[rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) is used only for *queries*, i.e., SQL statements that return data.
For other statements (such as your INSERT), you must use [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29).